# crud-generator : Error 404 on view files

Tags: mean, meanjs, yo

So after installing the MeanJS stack, I used the crud module generator :

```
yo meanjs:crud-module posts
```

Everything worked fine but when I click a link in the new Post menu I got :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/modules/posts/client/views/list-posts.client.view.html 404 (Not Found)
```

The file do exists though, I checked the routes and stuffs but everything seems ok.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posts.client.routes.js just change the templateUrl to '**modules/posts/views/form-program.client.view.html**' from '**modules/posts/client/views/form-program.client.view.html**'

It worked for me